# Test of difference: 2 KS tests or one?

Tags: spss, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have two unrelated groups and am looking to perform a test for difference. Before I can do that, I need to perform a Kolmogorov–Smirnov (KS) test for normal distribution so I can decide whether to do the independent t-test or Mann–Whitney U.

In SPSS, do I perform one KS test for the entire population or 1 for each group?

(These are the tests given as required on the assignment briefing.)

(If it helps, the independent variable is small and large dog breeds. The dependent variable of interest is aggression on a scale of 1–10)

Answer (score 1):

To address your question, there are pros and cons of both approaches. Technically the assumption is normality in each sample, which suggests two tests, however this is multiple testing and therefore has either an increased type I error probability, or bad power when corrected with Bonferroni. A test with both samples taken together (after centering them both to mean zero) is better in this respect, but may miss if both samples are non-normal in complementary ways so that they look normal taken together (which in practice is rather unlikely but not impossible).

However, the more important thing in my view is that a KS-test in order to check normality before a two sample t-test is not recommended; if you want to do normality testing at all, Anderson-Darling and Shapiro-Wilk are better than KS for this task, and what's more, whether running a two-sample t-test is good conditionally on a preliminary normality test is controversial at best, see Sec. 5.2 and 5.3 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.02218 and the references given there.

In fact, I gather that you have discrete values that can take values 1-10. These cannot be normal anyway (the normal distribution is continuous and can take unbounded values), but on the other hand a t-test will usually be OK for such data because the major problem with normality that can mislead results is gross outliers, which you usually don't have with such scales, unless the distribution is *very* extreme.

Note that normality of the data is *not* essential for the t-test (no real data are perfectly normal), what is essential is only that nothing happens that invalidates the test. This is also argued in the arxiv paper linked above.

On the other hand, some people would argue that your data are in fact ordinal and means and variances as involved in the t-test are not meaningful, for which reason they would suggest to run a Wilcoxon test, which doesn't use the values at interval scale level.

There is a long running discussion about whether methods such as t-tests are OK for ordinal data. I'd probably not object against using it and may do it myself (knowing my data, where they come from, and what exactly I want to find out).

However all this has nothing to do with what a preliminary KS-test could tell you, which I don't think is of any use here.

Comment: Thank you but to tick the boxes required for this assessment, a KS test is asked for. And if I run it on the entire population, it indicated normal distribution, if I split the samples and run a test on each, its not normal distribution. And I just need to pass this assignment.

Comment: I can say what I know about these tests. I have no idea how your assignment is marked.

Comment: I am very grateful; reading your response and going back over the assignment I can see where I think the assignment is misleading and actually I can see you are right and I'm overcomplicating thing.s Its just I find statistical analysis very daunting and our "taught" degree is proving to be very "self-directed." Thank you for your help and my apologies if I came across as ungrateful and dismissive.